# iPhone pair iphone bluetooth with media audio but not with phone audio

Tags: iphone, audio, bluetooth

I just switched from Android to an iPhone.  With Android, once the phone pairs with a bluetooth device, I can go into the settings for that device and determine which bluetooth interfaces it uses.  For instance, for the radio in the car, I can set it up to handle media audio, but not phone audio.

Is there a way to do this with an iPhone?